# Response Error 500 in Spring (HttpStatus field null pointer)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have build a rest web service using spring. I am getting 500 server error when the service is called.

Controller class :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/wordlist", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public ResponseEntity getList(@RequestHeader("wordid") int wordId) {  
    ResponseList responseObejct = wordService.getList(wordId); 
    return ResponseEntity.status(responseObejct.getStatusCode()).body(responseObejct.getResponseWordList());
}
```

DaoImplementation :

```
String listHql = "from Word where wordId > ? or wordId = ?";
Query query = session.createQuery(listHql);
query.setParameter(0, wordId);
query.setParameter(1, wordId);
query.setMaxResults(30);
        
if(query.list().size()>0){
    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
    response.setResponseWordList((ArrayList<Word>)query.list());
} else {
    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

ResponseList.java (for response)

```
public class ResponseList {
    
    private ArrayList<Word> responseWordList;
    private HttpStatus statusCode ;
            
    public ArrayList<Word> getResponseWordList() {
        return responseWordList;
    }
    
    public void setResponseWordList(ArrayList<Word> responseWordList) {
        this.responseWordList = responseWordList;
    }

    public HttpStatus getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(HttpStatus statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }       
        
}
```

Error is:

```
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set final org.springframework.http.HttpStatus field 
org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.statusCode to java.util.ArrayList
    sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    sun.reflect.UnsafeQualifiedObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeQualifiedObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:38)
    java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:86)
    com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
    com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:586)
    com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:565)
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.GsonHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(GsonHttpMessageConverter.java:199)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:100)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:183)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

I cannot understand why the error is coming. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are calling `ResponseEntity.status()` is not valid.
It says

```
The method status(HttpStatus) is undefined for the type 
ResponseEntity
```

To fix this try returning a ResponseEntity from your controller method like :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/wordlist", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public ResponseEntity<ResponseList> getList(@RequestHeader("wordid") int wordId) {  
     ResponseList responseObejct = wordService.getList(wordId); 
     ResponseEntity<ResponseList> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(responseObejct, HttpStatus.OK);
     return responseEntity;
}
```

Comment: are you saying that the method status does not exist on ResponseEntity? If so, It does exists http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html#status-org.springframework.http.HttpStatus-

Comment: It does exist but it expects an `int` and not a `HttpStatus`  object as a parameter. Checkout the status method [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html#status-int-).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and it turned out that this was fixed in Spring 4.3.1.
However, I cannot find a JIRA issue for that. Maybe it is a side-effect on another fix.

If you still have the problem (or if anyone else steps into this), please try again with 4.3.1 or higher.

Comment: I am a big disappointed about the down-vote. I ran exactly into this issue, and the upgrade to a newer Spring version may also help someone else solve this, as it did for me.