# How to add http status to all responses dto(data transfer object)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, dto

I've been developing a Spring Boot REST API. I've done so many things so far except my problem. I'm using springfox swagger UI for documentation, and I separated models and dtos for better structure.

**I have a base dto model:**

```
public class BaseDto {

 private int code;
 private boolean success;

 public BaseDto() {
    this.code = HttpStatus.OK.value();
    this.success = HttpStatus.OK.is2xxSuccessful();
 }
```

}

And of course I'm using this class by extending it like:

```
@ApiModel("User")
public class UserDto extends BaseDto {
    private String email;
    private String username;
    // stuffs
}
```

If I do user requests when I use this structure, I get:

```
{
  code: 200,
  success: true,
  email: "",
  username: ""
}
```

and so on... That's fine, but in other dtos, like post model, I have List of UserDto and it's showed in that form. In every object, "code" and "success" fields are written; however, this is not I want to.

The goal that I want to achieve is only once "code" and "success" are written in the response JSON body not all returning list objects.

To clarify more this is Post Dto Model and returns like this:

```
{
  "code": 0,
  "createdAt": "2016-05-17T21:59:37.512Z",
  "id": "string",
  "likes": [
    {
      "code": 0,
      "createdAt": "2016-05-17T21:59:37.512Z",
      "deviceType": "string",
      "email": "string",
      "fbAccessToken": "string",
      "fbId": "string",
      "followers": [
        {}
      ],
      "followings": [
        {}
      ],
      "id": "string",
      "profileImage": "string",
      "success": true,
      "token": "string",
      "udid": "string",
      "updatedAt": "2016-05-17T21:59:37.512Z",
      "username": "string",
      "version": 0
    }
  ],
  "pictures": [
    "string"
  ],
  "postedBy": {
    "code": 0,
    "createdAt": "2016-05-17T21:59:37.512Z",
    "deviceType": "string",
    "email": "string",
    "fbAccessToken": "string",
    "fbId": "string",
    "followers": [
      {}
    ],
    "followings": [
      {}
    ],
    "id": "string",
    "profileImage": "string",
    "success": true,
    "token": "string",
    "udid": "string",
    "updatedAt": "2016-05-17T21:59:37.512Z",
    "username": "string",
    "version": 0
  },
  "success": true,
  "text": "string",
  "updatedAt": "2016-05-17T21:59:37.512Z",
  "userId": "string",
  "userIds": [
    "string"
  ],
  "version": 0
}
```

You can see at Post Dto model where User Dto is used, code and success fields are added redundant.

I don't know most probably I got wrong approach. Perhaps, I should use adding global HTTP status response to all returning DTOs.

Can anyone help?

Comment: were you able to resolve this @saxahan ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have an AppUtil class were you can create your response and set `HttpStatus`. In your AppUtil class write a method like so :

```
public static ResponseEntity<ResponseEnvelope> successResponse(Object data,
        int messageCode, String message) {
    ResponseEnvelope envelope = new ResponseEnvelope(data, true, message,
            messageCode);
    ResponseEntity<ResponseEnvelope> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(
            envelope, HttpStatus.OK);
    return responseEntity;
}
```

In the `successResponse` method you can set your `data` object in the `ResponseEnvelope` which along with the `HttpStatus` will be sent in the `ResponseEntity` that you want to return.

Check out my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36532452/response-error-500-in-spring-httpstatus-field-null-pointer/36532812#36532812)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'll turn all my api calls to ResponseEntity, but it still there is no http status fields embeded in returning Json. How could I do that?

Comment: Get statusCode using HttpStatus statusCode = responseEntity.getStatusCode(); OR else you will have to explicitly add it your json.